# How to slow down camera movement?

Tags: modeling, photogrammetry

I am trying to do photomatching in blender where I need to manually match the camera position to the object I'm modelling. My source image has really small focal length 13mm which makes the camera movement too fast. I'm holding shift and the camera still pans around too fast. Is there any way to fix this? Make the camera move slower?

Only thing I can imagine is using my mouse adjustable dpi and put to its smallest setting but sometimes even that is too fast. I'd guess I could adjust windows mouse speed but that is awful to have to fiddle with on constant basis. As long as I can remember blender perspective mode has had this issue which is why I always try to do as much as possible in orthographic mode... maybe there is an addon that fixes this?

Comment: how are you moving around your camera? Are you using lock camera to view? Or are you pressing R or G and moving it like that?

Comment: Both. I use lock to camera view and then use the transform tools (r, g, s) and and 3d cursor as pivot. It is very finicky to line up the image so I'd need all the precision but instead I get hyperactivity and wrist issues :)

Comment: Did you find a solution ?